# alpha value captured by camera in ios

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make a fake shadow by using RenderTexture

i dynamically create a camera, and assign a RenderTexture to the camera as render target.
the format of the RenderTexture is set to ARGB32

then i use the RenderTexture as texture on a plane with a custom shader to change the color to black and adjust the alpha value so the shadow can be properly shown

below is the shader im using:

```
Shader "Fake Shadow" {
    Properties {
        _ShadowTex ("Fake Shadow", 2D) = "white" { TexGen ObjectLinear }
        _SAlpha ("Shadow Intensity", float) = 0.35
    }
    Category {
        Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent-1" }
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite On
        Cull Back
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha, one one
        Subshader { 
            LOD 200

            Pass {
                SetTexture[_ShadowTex] {
                    ConstantColor(0,0,0,[_SAlpha])
                    matrix [_ProjMatrix] 
                      Combine texture * constant, texture * constant
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

things are normal when i test play in Unity3D editor and on Android
however, the result is not correct in ios

the result image is in the link below (sorry i cant post image yet)

[shadow in editor](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6A4nhgcfBbWV3RiQWRxNTZIVW8/view?usp=sharing)
[shadow in ios](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6A4nhgcfBbWNFlhNGN6SFZINDQ/view?usp=sharing)

it seems ios put alpha as 1 in the RenderTexture even on pixels which the camera captured nothing

i have found a solution to solve this problem which is to check 32-bit display in the player settings
but im worried that checking 32-bit display will affect the performance

is there any other solution without checking 32-bit display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing the same thing (camera and projector for emulating shadows), and I use a shader based on the one on this page: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Projectors

The shader follows:

```
Shader "Cg projector shader for drop shadows" {
   Properties {
      _ShadowTex ("Projected Image", 2D) = "white" {}
      _ShadowStrength ("Shadow Strength", Float) = 0.65
   }
   SubShader {
      Pass {      
//          Blend Off
          Blend Zero OneMinusSrcAlpha // attenuate color in framebuffer 
            // by 1 minus alpha of _ShadowTex
            // fb_color = black + fb_color * OneMinusShadowAlpha;
         CGPROGRAM

         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag

         // User-specified properties
         uniform sampler2D _ShadowTex;

         uniform float _ShadowStrength;

         // Projector-specific uniforms
         uniform float4x4 _Projector; // transformation matrix 
            // from object space to projector space 

          struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float3 normal : NORMAL;
         };
         struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float4 posProj : TEXCOORD0;
               // position in projector space
         };

         vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input) 
         {
            vertexOutput output;

            output.posProj = mul(_Projector, input.vertex);
            output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, input.vertex);
            return output;
         }


         float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
         {
            if (input.posProj.w > 0.0) // in front of projector?
            {
               return tex2D(_ShadowTex , 
                  float2(input.posProj) / input.posProj.w) * _ShadowStrength;
            }
            else // behind projector
            {
               return float4(0.0);
            }
         }

         ENDCG
      }
   }  
   // The definition of a fallback shader should be commented out 
   // during development:
   // Fallback "Projector/Light"
}
```

Comment: do you mean the camera renders to RenderTexture, and show the shadow with a projector?

Comment: Yeah. Something else to note is that that camera has clear flags = "Solid Color", with the background=white, alpha=0. It has a mask so it only sees the objects you need fake shadows for, and definitely not the ground. Likewise, the projector is ignoring all layers except the ground. Let me know if you have other questions, since my setup sounds the same as what you want. You want dark spots projected onto the ground, where the dark spot is a non-colored rendering of the object, yeah?